# TeX Live Installation failed at the very end!

Tags: errors, miktex, texlive, installing

I installed MiKTex two days before. After trying so hard for hours, I couldn't figure out why MikTex couldn't run properly (There was some error saying "Trouble converting to xdv"). I couldn't find a proper fix, but internet suggested to go for TeX Live.

So I chose to completely remove MikTex and Install Tex Live from https://www.tug.org/texlive/ on my Windows 10.

After 15 hours of getting all the packages, I get this message,

```
Installing [4177/4177, time/total: 15:19:50/15:23:50]: zztex [147k]
Retrying to install: pxjahyper [146k]
TeXLive::TLUtils::check_file_and_remove: checksums differ for C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Temp\Mv7OSXTvG5\q45WeBdP9o/pxjahyper.tar.xz:
TeXLive::TLUtils::check_file_and_remove:   tlchecksum=e1e8d78be8c9de9168d66c8189b8e5268530ff3e2ad20eccf652d4017de80db779253963fc84935498a573c0acb6013c932ef94540604b1be0e1113bc154d209, arg=416353c1cd02e7047e9cb76d2f37cc028d46c8f5197cce005f35fb6e22bdf3f0ce90fa568eebdcd7fed8581063f9f3ab1a59d4beefa3b266d0ab0a296baebf81
TeXLive::TLUtils::check_file_and_remove: backtrace:
 -> C:/Users/pc/AppData/Local/Temp/nsyE108.tmp/install-tl-20210530/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLUtils.pm:2399: TeXLive::TLUtils::check_file_and_remove
 -> C:/Users/pc/AppData/Local/Temp/nsyE108.tmp/install-tl-20210530/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPDB.pm:1978: TeXLive::TLUtils::unpack
 -> C:/Users/pc/AppData/Local/Temp/nsyE108.tmp/install-tl-20210530/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPDB.pm:1813: TeXLive::TLPDB::_install_data
 -> C:/Users/pc/AppData/Local/Temp/nsyE108.tmp/install-tl-20210530/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPDB.pm:1729: TeXLive::TLPDB::not_virtual_install_package
 -> C:/Users/pc/AppData/Local/Temp/nsyE108.tmp/install-tl-20210530/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLUtils.pm:1633: TeXLive::TLPDB::install_package
 -> C:/Users/pc/AppData/Local/Temp/nsyE108.tmp/install-tl-20210530/install-tl:2135: TeXLive::TLUtils::install_packages
 -> C:/Users/pc/AppData/Local/Temp/nsyE108.tmp/install-tl-20210530/install-tl:946: main::do_install_packages
 -> C:/Users/pc/AppData/Local/Temp/nsyE108.tmp/install-tl-20210530/install-tl:700: main::do_installation
TeXLive::TLUtils::check_file_and_remove:   removing C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Temp\Mv7OSXTvG5\q45WeBdP9o/pxjahyper.tar.xz, but saving copy in C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Temp\Ts46kbHjN1
TLPDB::_install_data: downloading did not succeed (check_file_and_remove failed) for https://mirror.las.iastate.edu/tex-archive/systems/texlive/tlnet/archive/pxjahyper.tar.xz
Installation failed.
Rerunning the installer will try to restart the installation.
  Or you can restart by running the installer with:
  install-tl-windows.bat --profile installation.profile [YOUR-EXTRA-ARGS]
or
  install-tl-advanced.bat --profile installation.profile [YOUR-EXTRA-ARGS]
C:/Users/pc/AppData/Local/Temp/nsyE108.tmp/install-tl-20210530/install-tl: Writing log in current 
directory: C:/Users/pc/AppData/Local/Temp/nsyE108.tmp/install-tl.log
```

I tried re-installing, but the installer starts it again from scratch!!

Is there anyway to fix this problem? Any help is very much appreciated!

Thank You!

Comment: At best write to the texlive mailing list. (And perhaps download the files with wget or rsync first. Then you can reinstall from local files if needed, this should speed up the installation a lot).

Comment: If you are `windows` user, please try the installation with `admin` rights...

Comment: @MadyYuvi no admin rights are not needed. I could install texlive without them without problems.